# ASP.NET How to reuse jQuery event handlers across more than one cshtml file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have this method for adding a global event handler, so I can check on each ajax request whether a response header has been added and how to respond to that.

This works absolutely fine, but I need it in more than one view (cshtml). So rather than duplicating it in every file, is there a way I could extract this out so I can call it from other files or apply this globally to all my views?

```
    $(document).ajaxSuccess(function(event, request, settings) {
        if (request.getResponseHeader('ResponseHeader') === '1') {
            window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")';
        }
    });
```

The code itself isn't super important, just more about whether it's possible to reuse these across all my views without duplicating it. I was also thinking about creating a global event handler that would check the http status code response from all ajax requests, then respond to the codes appropriately i.e. redirect any 404 codes to a not found page for example. There must be a way to achieve this or something similar rather than copying this across every single ajax call?

The main language I use is C# and I'm a beginner with using JavaScript / jQuery, so any extra explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

*jQuery version: 1.10.2*

Comment: ...would adding a single shared .js file to your pages not work?

Comment: That being said, Ajax is not supposed to influence your view like that. You wouldn't want to redirect the entire view to a 404 page when an Ajax request fails with a 404 code. You'd want to display an error message in an appropriate spot.

Comment: @Tomalak I did try to make a js file and use the <script></script> to see if I could import it and use the functions on it but I have any luck getting that working. Do you know a way I could use a shared file like that? 

Perhaps a more appropriate use would be to use a toastr notification with some information about what went wrong to the user rather than a redirect.

Comment: A notification would certainly be better. If using `<script>` did not work the way you thought, share what you have tried.

Comment: I made a js file, used the code above but wrapped it in a "function testMethod() { }". Then I used <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Test.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> in my cshtml file. Then I tried to call this using $.testMethod(); in the console it says that testMethod is not a function.

Comment: `$` (typically) is jQuery. If you have a stand-alone function called `testMethod()` you can call it without `$.`.

Comment: Ah, that's really helpful to know. I was also trying to put the jQuery event handler inside a js function and call that... which would've been ideal to cut down on repeating any code but not sure it was right. But anyhow, I've got a shared js script with a function in it now which will be useful in for other things. Thank you for your help!